# Укажите на ошибки или на что обратить внимание

Tags: c#, массивы, циклы

Я только начинаю не судите строго.
Дан двумерный массив A из n строк и n столбцов. Необходимо произвести поиск в массиве А по заданному условию, соблюдая указанную очередность обхода элементов. Если поиск даст положительный результат, требуется вывести на экран результат поиска, если отрицательный – изменить исходный массив (или создать одномерный массив X) по заданному правилу и вывести на экран результат изменения.

Значение функции tan x, где x – величина первого элемента, попавшего в интервал (–π / 2; π / 2).
Создать одномерный массив, состоящий из значений элементов матрицы, расположенных одновременно над главной и побочной диагоналями, выбирая элементы построчно.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace zad_
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Введите размер массива");
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            double pi = Math.PI;
            int [,] A = new int[n, n];
            int[] mas = new int[] {};
            Console.WriteLine("Двумерный массив с рандомным наполнением");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    A[i, j] = rand.Next(20);
                    Console.Write(A[i, j] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Массив из элементов выше главной и побочной диагоналей двумерного массива");
            for (int i = 1; i < n / 2 - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < n / 2 + 1; j++)
                {
                    mas[i - 1] = A[i, j];
                    Console.Write(mas[i-1] + "\t");
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++)
            {
                if ((mas[i] > pi) && (mas[i] < pi))
                {
                    double tan = Math.Tan(mas[i]);
                    Console.WriteLine("тангенс первого элемента попавшего в интервал" + tan);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не совсем ясно, что вы от нас хотите? Есть в коде ошибки или нет? Если есть, то какие? Если нет, то что вам нужно?

Comment: Поскольку в описании использовано слово "диагональ", то один из циклов явно должен как-то зависеть от другого (в жизни переменной `j` как-то должна участвовать переменная `i`). Без такой зависимости вы сможете перебрать вложенными циклами только квадратный участок матрицы, но никак не диагональ.

Comment: Интересно, какой ожидается результат у сравнения `(mas[i] > pi) && (mas[i] < pi)`, то есть, вы полагаете, что может существовать некое число, которое было бы _одновременно_ и больше π, и меньше π?

Answer (score 0):

Собственно, а где поиск? Поиск по заданному условию подразумевает использование сравнения в том или ином виде, но его нигде не видно! После поиска должна быть проверка его успешности и две ветки выполнения программы, где это всё?

Comment: Это больше похоже на комментарий, чем на ответ.

Comment: @aepot Да нет вроде, какой вопрос, такой и ответ) Человек спросил на что обратить внимание